# How can I catch the new questions on stackoverflow with webdriver without constantly refreshing the web page?

Tags: ajax, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

How can I catch the new questions on stackoverflow with webdriver without constantly refreshing the web page? If I constantly execute a web scraping file, it will waste a lot of traffic.